# Tangents of ellipse going through a point outside of it

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have an ellipse: 5x^(2) + 9y^(2) = 45; and a point M = [0; -3]; how do I find tangents of said ellipse that go through the point M?
Please, help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214977/general-equation-of-a-tangent-line-to-a-hyperbola

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834392/equations-of-lines-tangent-to-an-ellipse and many others.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: because of the symmetry in this problem, an easy way to find the solution is to compute the polar of $M$ and its intersections with the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the tangent line going through $M$ touches the ellipse at $(x_0, y_0)$. Then the equation of tangent line on that point is
$$5x_0x+9y_0y = 45$$
Since this line goes through $M=(0, 3)$, We have $y_0=-\frac{5}{3}$.

Also because $(x_0, y_0)$ is on the ellipse, it satisfies $5x^2+9y^2=45$, so plugging in $y_0 = \frac{5}{3}$ would give $x_0 = \pm 2$.

Thus the final answer is
$$\pm 2x-3y=9$$

---

A bit of additional explanation for how I got the tangent line:
Calculating the derivative (implicit function) gives $$10x+18y\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
thus the slope of the tangent line on $(x_0, y_0)$ would be $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{5x_0}{9y_0}$$
So the equation would be 
$$y-y_0 = -\frac{5x_0}{9y_0}(x-x_0)$$
and simplifying with $5x_0^2+9y_0^2=45$ will give
$$5x_0x + 9y_0y=45$$

---

This is actually a useful technique for calculating tangent lines on conic sections. Generally, tangent line to $Ax^2+By^2=C$ on $(x_0, y_0)$ is
$$Ax_0x+By_0y=C$$
(Just replace $x^2$ with $x_0x$, $y^2$ with $y_0y$)

Answer (score 0):

We have given $$M(0;-3)$$ and our tangentline has the form
$$y=mx-3$$ plugging this in the equation of our Ellipse we get
$$5x^2+9(mx-3)^2=45$$, now you must compute $m$ such that this equation has only one solution.
This is $$45m^2-20=0$$

Comment: And could you please explain how do I go from 5x^2+9(mx−3)^2=45 to 45m^2−20=0?

Comment: Using the quadratic formula we get

Comment: $$x_1=3\,{\frac {9\,m+\sqrt {45\,{m}^{2}-20}}{9\,{m}^{2}+5}}$$

Comment: $$x_2=-3\,{\frac {-9\,m+\sqrt {45\,{m}^{2}-20}}{9\,{m}^{2}+5}}$$